# Access Panel from Main Form from a Panel Form

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to access a panel from my Main JForm which I use as a dynamic panel that repaints different Panel Forms.

this is the hierarchy of the forms.

  Package_Main
    -Main_Form(JForm)
      -Dynamic_Panel(Panel)
    -DashBoard(Panel_Form)
  Package_Panels
    -Panel_A
    -Panel_B

What I did was Display JForm first and repaint its JPanel with DashBoard.
now heres the problem.
I have a button inside my dashboard and when I tried to import Package_Panels.PanelA, but it doesn't work properly.

heres the first code I tried:

This code was added inside DashBoard Button.

```
PanelA x = new PanelA ();
this.removeAll();
this.add(x);
this.revalidate();
this.repaint();
x.setVisible(true);
```

I had doubts about this one since I knew if i use `this.function`, it points out the DashBoard Panel.

anyone knows a way to access the JForm's panel?

UPDATE: I found a way around this by using `this.getParent()` but other ideas are welcome. I don't to be stuck doing this over and over again.

heres what I did:

```
Panel_A x = new Panel_A();
this.setVisible(false);
this.getParent().add(x);
this.getParent().revalidate();
this.getParent().repaint();
x.setVisible(true);
//this.getParent().remove(this); - Does this really work? I dont want to keep this instance open.
```

Comment: First, consider using a CardLayout to dynamically update the UI. Second, pass a reference of Main_Form to what ever classes need to be able to interact with it. Actually, using some kind of observer pattern might Ne prettier, when the DashBoard generates events that the Main_Form (in this case) can listener for, which it can then decide what it needs to do in response

Comment: `PanelA` & `Panel_A`  .. for programmer's sake give them meaningful names!

Comment: @AndrewThompson well, its just a sample name. what I'm working is a patient management module.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wish I could post a picture of what my program looks like but thats the only way I could depict the layouts. Im using border layout since I have a button panel on the left, right and top.

Comment: *"..its just a sample name"*  If it were only for your use, it would be fine.  But when communicating a problem to others, use more sensible names. *"I wish I could post a picture of what my program looks like but thats the only way I could depict the layouts."*  Look up 'ASCII art'.  In any case, if you upload a pic. to an image share site and edit the link into the question, if someone with more rep. **thinks it is relevant** they might embed the pic.